# how to send parameter to php page via post when a dynamically created <li> tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My main code is

```html
<div class="border_circular row">
     <ul id="circulars_slider">
         <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($circular)){
         ?>
            <li>
              <p><?php echo $row['title']; ?></p>
            </li>
         <?php } ?>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Now in above code number of `<li>` tags are created based on number of rows in mysql table.

I need a solution to send `$row['title']` variable to a `some.php` file via post method **but only when that particular `<li>` is clicked.**

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far that didn't work? May I ask why POST?

Comment: Use form `POST` method or button click `AJAX` method to pass your post value.

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` is **server side scripting language**.

Without any action you cant pass the values.

So use form `POST` method or button click `AJAX` method to pass your post value.

I hope it will help you..!